# Parsing Interview Text

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have a text file of a presidential debate. Eventually, I want to parse the text into a dataframe where each row is a statement, with one column with the speaker's name and another column with the statement. For example:

```
"Bob Smith: Hi Steve. How are you doing? Steve Brown: Hi Bob. I'm doing well!"
```

Would become:

```
   name          text
1   Bob Smith    Hi Steve. How are you doing?
2 Steve Brown    Hi Bob. I'm doing well!
```

Question: How do I split the statements from the names? I tried splitting on the colon:

```
data <- strsplit(data, split=":")
```

But then I get this:

```
"Bob Smith" "Hi Steve. How are you doing? Steve Brown" "Hi Bob. I'm doing well!"
```

When what I want is this:

```
"Bob Smith" "Hi Steve. How are you doing?" "Steve Brown" "Hi Bob. I'm doing well!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this will fix all of your parsing needs, but an approach using `strsplit` to solve your most immediate question is using lookaround. You'll need to use perl regex though.

Here you instruct strsplit to split on either `:` or a space where there is a punctuation character immediately before and nothing but alphanumeric characters or spaces between the space and `:`. `\\pP` matches punctuation characters and `\\w` matches word characters.

```
data <- "Bob Smith: Hi Steve. How are you doing? Steve Brown: Hi Bob. I'm doing well!"
strsplit(data,split="(: |(?<=\\pP) (?=[\\w ]+:))",perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Bob Smith"                    "Hi Steve. How are you doing?" "Steve Brown"                 
[4] "Hi Bob. I'm doing well!"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can extract these with regex using the `stringr` package. You then directly have the columns of speaker and quote you are looking for.

```r
a <- "Bob: Hi Steve. Steve: Hi Bob."

library(stringr)

str_match_all(a, "([A-Za-z]*?): (.*?\\.)")
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]             [,2]    [,3]       
#> [1,] "Bob: Hi Steve." "Bob"   "Hi Steve."
#> [2,] "Steve: Hi Bob." "Steve" "Hi Bob."
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to generalize a little. What if we remove the assumption that each statement is a single sentence ending with a period? What if the speaker is named "Bob Smith" instead of "Bob"