# Find two words before match

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to split a string using regex. My regex code is supposed to match the two words that come before a colon, with the ultimate goal of splitting something like this:

```
"Joe Biden: We need to reform healthcare. It is important. Bernie Sanders: I agree. It is important."
```

into a vector of strings like this:

```
"Joe Biden" "We need to reform healthcare. It is important." "Bernie Sanders" "I agree. It is important"
```

The closest i've gotten is this:

```
foo <- strsplit(my_string, split="(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*:",perl=TRUE)
```

But the result removes the regex matches. I tried using lookbehind like this:

```
foo <- strsplit(my_string, split="(?<=.)(?=(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*:)",perl=TRUE)
```

But it throws an error:

```
  PCRE pattern compilation error
    'lookbehind assertion is not fixed length'
    at ')'
```

Is there alternative regex code to accomplish this, or a different function I should be using?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that is different than your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778339/)?

Comment: The last answer is very helpful, but only if statements end in punctuation. For some statements, the moderator interrupts the speaker mid-sentence so there is no punctuation. Matching on the two words prior to a colon (speaker's name) would catch all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This splits on two things separated by the or operator `|`.  1) a space that is followed by two words separated by a space and then a colon and 2) a colon followed by a space.

```
my_string <- "Joe Biden: We need to reform healthcare. It is important. Bernie Sanders: I agree. It is important."
strsplit(my_string, split="( (?=\\w+ \\w+:)|: )",perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Joe Biden"            "We need to reform healthcare. It is important."
[3] "Bernie Sanders"       "I agree. It is important."
```

The trouble you'll run into here is if the name of the speaker is only one word. That was the purpose of looking for the punctuation in my answer to your previous question.